# execute commands of another program from a tidesdk program

Tags: java, console, cmd, titanium, tidesdk

I'm testing [tidesdk](http://www.tidesdk.org/).

I have a java program that reads from standard input.
I run the program through the console console

```
java -cp MyProgram.jar package.MyMainClass
```

And then execute commands and get results.

there any way to do with tidesdk?

**Edit:** 
  The problem was that calls the java program with a list of one element (which contained the command separated by spaces)
It solved with passing every word to a item of  list (and removing the spaces).
Right now I have porblemas to write standard input. This is what I'm trying.

```
 var input = Ti.Process.createPipe();

 var process = Ti.Process.createProcess({
                   args:['java', '-cp', 'C:/.../MyProgram.jar', 'package.MyMainClass'],
                   stdin: input
                });

    //process.setOnReadLine(function(line) { alert(line) });
    process.launch();

    input.write("comand parameter1 parameter2\n"); //This line does not work
```

The java program starts. But never gets a command.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Documentation of Ti.Process.createProcess. That is exactly what you are looking for:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Process

Comment: thank you very much. I edited the question to explain the problem I'm having. Java program does not get any command from standard input.

Comment: I would generally pass the required parameters at onset as commandline parameters to the process.

This may be a not implemented feature or a bug in process class. We will have a look at it. Can you please file an issue https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues

Comment: I created the issue https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/190 I hope you understand. thanks