# Call a JAVA class method from TideSDK

Tags: java, javascript, tidesdk

I am trying to create an application for which I have JAVA files at the backend ready. I am trying to create UI for the same project for which I am trying through TideSDK and I am new to it. I need to call a JAVA class method from tideSDK by passing some parameters and get response from the same. Is there any way to connect TideSDK with JAVA ?

Comment: a while ago I make a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486779/execute-commands-of-another-program-from-a-tidesdk-program